# Healenium Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: java, docker, appium, healenium

I am new to Healenium and have been trying to run Android native app tests using Healnium-Appium. I tried all the possible things but not able to to get rid of the below error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-******', ip: '192.***.**.*'
    at healenium.TestEmulatorLoginForm.setUp(TestEmulatorLoginForm.java:48)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpHandler,java.io.InputStream,long)
Build info: version: '4.9.0', revision: 'd7057100a6'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.4.1'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
    at healenium.TestEmulatorLoginForm.setUp(TestEmulatorLoginForm.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpHandler,java.io.InputStream,long)
    at healenium.TestEmulatorLoginForm.setUp(TestEmulatorLoginForm.java:48)
```

Tried with RemoteWebDriver but it didn't work. I have all the setup - Docker, Appium server and Emulator running but no luck seem to be in my part.